# using grepl with case_when to clean up dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working with a few datasets that have all entered data in slightly different formats that I'm trying to clean up using dplyr and grepl.  One of the variables I'm struggling with is a factor that I have a few decision rules for:

1. if the category is a single factor, then no change (e.g., AB = AB)
2. if the category is a single factor with a question mark, then drop the question mark (e.g., AC? = AC)
3. if the category is two factors separated by |, / or ?, then replace with NA (e.g., AB|B = NA or AC? B? = NA)

At present, my code looks similar to this:

```
cat <- c("A", "AB", "B", "C?", "AC|C", "A", "B/A", "C?", "B?", "A|B", "C? B?", "A", "B?", "B", "B")
df <- as.data.frame(cat)
mutate(df,
       cat = case_when(grepl("|", cat) ~ NA_character_,
                       grepl("/", cat) ~ NA_character_,
                       grepl("? ", cat) ~ NA_character_, 
                       TRUE ~ cat))
```

If this worked, it would help me address the rules 1 and 3, but at present it just returns NA's for all the fields.
Also, I'm not sure how to drop the ? for variables that just have a single letter (rule 2).

Comment: `grepl("[|/?]", cat)` might do.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew would I use that like of code to replace the current first 3 lines of the case_when function?  Like:
mutate(df,
cat = case_when(grepl("[|/?]", cat) ~ NA_character_,
                       TRUE ~ cat)
That certainly helps with Rule 3, but the values in Rule 2 also become NAs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer lies in the syntax and I should have included [] in my initial code.

```
cat <- c("A", "AB", "B", "C?", "AC|C", "A", "B/A", "C?", "B?", "A|B", "C? B?", "A", "B?", "B", "B")
df <- as.data.frame(cat)
mutate(df,
       cat = case_when(grepl("[|]", cat) ~ NA_character_,
                       grepl("[/]", cat) ~ NA_character_,
                       grepl("[?]", cat) ~ NA_character_, 
                       TRUE ~ cat))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `grepl` and `case_when`, your stated goal could be achieved by removing all question marks, then if you are left with more than one character, make it `NA`, as demonstrated here:

```r
df %>% mutate(cat = sub("\\?", "", cat),
              cat = replace(cat, nchar(cat) > 1, NA))
#>     cat
#> 1     A
#> 2     A
#> 3     B
#> 4     C
#> 5  <NA>
#> 6     A
#> 7  <NA>
#> 8     C
#> 9     B
#> 10 <NA>
#> 11 <NA>
#> 12    A
#> 13    B
#> 14    B
#> 15    B
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I guess I was too clever for myself when writing my question.  My actual dataset has categories of varying length (i.e., with more than 1 letter), so unfortunately this approach wouldn't work although it is certainly much simpler than using grepl.

Comment: I guessed that might be the case @tnt - with text parsing, the solution is heavily dependent on the real data. There are bound to be shortcuts like I show above, but it depends on how many categories there are, their length etc. If you can't do it in a single regex, you should consider doing it iteratively.